# How to correctly make conditions in TinyButStrong?

Tags: php, odt, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I have to make a template in the TinyButStrong language, but I have no access to the PHP side. I'm just able to modify my template and to upload it on my ERP.

Anyway, the PHP side is working well.

I tried to put an `if` statement in my ODT template file, but when rendering it doesn't work.

My condition:

```
[if [tab.product_type]!=1; then ‘[tab.product_ref]’; else ‘0’; block=table:table-row]
```

I verified value of `tab.product_type`, and the value is 0 or 1.

I tried many syntaxes, but none is working well. The only thing that it shows is:

[image: Rendered PDF].

Where did I make a mistake? I really don't understand, because I tried many syntaxes and I still get this line.

Comment: With TBS, [if] is not a the name of a field, but the name of a parameter. A correct syntax could be `[tab.product_ref;block=table:table-row;if '[tab.product_type]'='1'; then '0']`, but in fact what to you want to achieve ?

Comment: Hi, I want to make a line with my tab.product_ref only if tab.product_type is not 1

Answer (score 0):

Little update :

I saw that the "when" is more adapted to this usage.
I found a syntax but I'm still having bad results. I made this :

```
[tab.product_ref;block=table:table-row;when [tab.product_type]!=1]
```

Anyway, it's giving me lines where tab.product_type is 1.
Why ?? I really don't understand how this language works...

Comment: `when` is a parameter for a conditional section of a block. The section is displayed only if the condition is checked. The section of the block is defined on the table row (`block=table:table-row`), so only rows with the checked condition are displayed.

Comment: But this last snippet should do your request : « I want to make a line with my tab.product_ref only if tab.product_type is not 1 ».